# loop over a list for the occurence of a list element

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I want to define a `majority` function that would give back the list element if that element occurs at least `(n/2)+1` times in the list, else prints out `None`(where n is the length of the list)

```
def majority(list):
    a = len(list)
    for i in list:
        if list.count(i) >= (a/2) +1:
            print(int(i))
        else:
            print("None")
```

However, the result of `majority([3,1,2,1,1,3,1])` is 7 times `None`. I'm not sure why this is the case

Comment: In Python3, you probably mean floor division `a // 2`.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked (output : `None 1 None 1 1 None 1`)

Comment: `(a/2) + 1` in this case is `4.5` and no count is more than `4.5` in this case - that's why you see None

Comment: `(a/2) + 1` is 4.5, none of your vals in `list.count(i)` are over that

Answer (score 2):

Python has a built in class for this called [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html).

```
from collections import Counter
a = [3,1,2,1,1,3,1]
cc = Counter(a)
x = cc.most_common(1)
if x and x[0][1] > len(a) // 2:
    print(x[0][0])
```

Output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is due to the differences between floating point division and integer division

- `/` represent floating point division in python, so `a/2 + 1` is 3.5 + 1 = 4.5
- `//` represent integer division, so `a//2 + 1` is 3 + 1 = 4

In this case we want to round towards zero with our length calculation so we want to use `//`

Alternatively you could also get by using floating point division and not adding 1

ie) `if list.count(i) >= a/2:`